# How to know when a command is prompting for input in Linux, C

Tags: c, input, process, fork

I'm making a minishell that can launch either fg and bg processes.
The problem is that if a child process **in background** is gonna ask for input from the user, the father prompt awaiting for the next command will take it instead.
How can i choose which process is gonna elaborate the input?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am not sure to understand you, if a process running in background read on *stdin* (not redirected) that process is suspended, that is all, the fact there are or not some other processes  started after the one in background is not relevant and changes nothing

Comment: when your shell does not execute a process in foreground the shell has *stdin*, when the shell execute a process in foreground that process get *stdin*, and the shell will get back *stdin* when the process ends or if it is stopped (eg control-z)

Comment: Since i'm making by myself the background logic i don't know if i can rely on this mechanic.

Comment: this is how that works since ages under Linux/Unix, why to invent a new behavior, to put people in trouble ?

Comment: @EdoardoRosso, it is your responsibility to implement that mechanic (but there are functions that will help you), because that's part of what "foreground" and "background" *mean* in this context.  Or else, what do you think it is supposed to mean for a process to be in the background?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much by definition, the terminal is owned by the foreground process. So the answer is, you cannot pick which process will handle the terminal input; it will always be a foreground one.

If your minishell *does not* handle redirection, you are doomed. If it does, you may, in Linux,

```
echo whatever input you have > /proc/PID/fd/0
```

(PID is a pid of the background process). Or use a named pipe.

Comment: No "pretty much" about it.  A program that has a controlling terminal and is a member of the process group that currently controls it is in the foreground (with respect to that terminal).  One that has a controlling terminal and is not in its controlling process group is in the background, and does not receive input from the terminal while it is there.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks for the clarification. It seems however that the notions of the process group and the controlling terminal are very Unix oriented. I wish I had the authoritative definition of what makes the process a process a foreground one (VxWorks? QNX? NT?)

Comment: The OP specifically names Linux in the question title, so UNIX-style notions of "foreground" and "background" are the natural ones in this context.  If you want to try to generalize to operating systems that have different senses of those terms then by all means go ahead, but it would be helpful to future readers if you make it clear that you are doing so.